# Report using lookup field

Tags: reporting, contact

I have lookup field (which is lookup to a object c) on account and the loopup object (c) contain a field name stage. Now i need to create a report on account on the base of different stage. For example: if i have 2 stage with name a and b where and 2 there are 2 records on c object records with different stage stage a-> A1 record and stage b-> B2 record, and now want to generate report on contact, on the base of stage on object c. Is it is possible, or is their any other way to do this task. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go about this. The first is to use formula fields to pull the value of Object C's "Stage" field onto the Account and/or Contact. Assuming that the Stage field is a Picklist, you would create a new Formula(Text) field on Account, and the formula would be something like this (adjust for actual object & field name):

```
TEXT(Object__r.Stage__c)
```

To create a formula on the Contact, it would be:

```
TEXT(Account.Object__r.Stage__c)
```

For best results, use the Insert Field button on the Advanced Formula builder. Once you have these formula fields, you can include them in regular Account & Contact reports.

Alternatively, you can [build Custom Report types](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_report_type_setup.htm&language=en_US), and [include this field by lookup](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_report_type_layouts.htm&language=en_US). If you have a need to include the